# Trace of a Matrix Product.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, analysis, vectors, trace

### Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$, and $B\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$. Let $A'$ denote the transpose of  $A$.

From this we know that :  $A'\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ and  $AB\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ and hence $ABA' \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$.

The Trace of a matrix is defined as the sum of its diagonal entries. $\textbf{My Question :}$

Does anyone know bounds (using any usual matrix norm) for

- $\text{Trace}(ABA')$
- Or more generally $\text{Trace}(AB)$

Comment: We can bound $|Tr(ABA')| \leq n \sigma_{Amax}^2|\lambda_{Bmax}|$ where $\sigma_{Amax}$ and $\lambda_{Bmax}$ are the largest (by absolute value) singular or eigen values of $A$ and $B$, respectively.

Comment: @NinadMunshi That is an amazing bound, and very useful, have you got a link to this/ or make it into an answer ? Thank you very much by the way. $TR(ABA')$ is the one i am most interested in.

Answer (score 10):

Whenever you see a matrix trace, you should think **inner product**, because

$$ \operatorname{Tr}(A^T B) = \langle A, B\rangle_F = \langle A,B\rangle_{\mathbb  R^m \otimes \mathbb R^n}$$

that is, the trace of the product of two matrices is equal to their frobenius inner product, which in turn is the induced inner product on the [tensor product of Hilbert spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product_of_Hilbert_spaces).

Since it is an inner product, the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality applies:

$$ |\langle A, B \rangle_F |^2 \le \|A\|_F^2\|B\|_F^2$$

with equality if and only if $A$ and $B$ are linearly dependent matrices, i.e. scaler multiples of each other. In your case, we have

$$ |\operatorname{Tr}(ABA^T)| = |\operatorname{Tr}(A^TA B)| = |\langle A^TA , B\rangle_F| \le \|A^TA\|_F\|B\|_F$$

The last term can be further bounded by

$$\begin{aligned}
\|A^TA\|_F\|B\|_F &\le \|A\|_F^2\|B\|_F = \Big(\sum\nolimits_i \sigma_i^2(A)\Big)\cdot\sqrt{\sum\nolimits_j \sigma_j^2(B)} 
\\ &\le rank(A)\cdot \sigma^2_{\max}(A)\cdot rank(B)\cdot\sigma_{\max}(B)\\
&\le m\cdot \min(m,n)\cdot  \sigma^2_{\max}(A)\cdot \sigma_{\max}(B)
\end{aligned}$$

Answer (score 2):

$$tr(C'B)= (vec(C))'(vec(B)) \leq \bigg[(vec(C))'(vec(C)) \bigg]\bigg[(vec(B))'(vec(B)) \bigg]$$
by *Cauchy Schwarz inequality*. Now let $C=A'$ you get a upper bound of $tr(AB)$.

Similary for $tr(ABA')=tr(BA'A)$

Answer (score 0):

The trace is merely the sum of the eigenvalues, so if we could find an estimate on the largest eigenvalue of $ABA'$, we could say that

$$|Tr(ABA')| \leq n\cdot|\lambda_{ABA'max}|$$

To that end we know that the eigenvalues of $ABA'$ are going to be some combination of the products of the singular values of $A$ and the eigenvalues of $B$. Take the biggest one of each to retrieve the bound:

$$|Tr(ABA')| \leq n \cdot \sigma_{Amax}^2\cdot|\lambda_{Bmax}|$$

$Tr(AB)$ is not defined because it is not a square matrix (In more abstract terms, $AB$ is not a trace-class operator).

Comment: Let $A$ be a matrix filled with ones, and $B$ be nilpotent, in particular say $B =\mathbf e_1 \mathbf e_2^T$  then $0\lt \Big \vert \text{trace}\big(ABA'\big)\Big\vert \leq n \cdot \sigma_{Amax}^2 \cdot \big \vert \lambda_{Bmax}\big\vert = 0$  which is a contradiction.  The eigenvalues of a non-normal $B$ cannot play a role in an upper bound.