# Trace of $BAB^{\top}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given two square matrices $A$ and $B$, is there any nice way to simplify $\operatorname{Tr} (BAB^{\top})$?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trace of a Matrix Product.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3602045/trace-of-a-matrix-product)

Comment: @DonThousand The question you linked is about computing bounds, not an exact value

Comment: @Leonardo What exactly do you mean by "simplify"? Right now, it's as if you asked "given numbers $a$ and $b$, is there any nice way to simplify $ab^2$?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know something about $B^TB$ then yes, using the cyclic property of the trace:
$$
\text{Tr}(BAB^T) = \text{Tr}(AB^T B) = \text{Tr}(B^TB A).
$$